# What is the completion award for completing the Nintendo Gallery

Tags: zelda-wind-waker

In WindWaker, there a place near Korok island that is the Nintendo Gallery; you bring a photo of a character there, and a statuette of that character will appear in the gallery.

You can probably do this with all the characters in the game. But if you do so, does something special happen?

Comment: Good luck collecting them all, if that is your goal. :) It took me a long time and two quests to do it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you successfully bring Carlov a picture for *every* figurine, the next time you come into the Nintendo Gallery Carlov won't be at the desk anymore. The guy usually found walking around ([Manny](http://zelda.wikia.com/wiki/Manny_(The_Wind_Waker))) will come up to you and say

> *"That manager guy is gone, you know... Yeah, he left one last figurine*
>   *and took off somewhere. I have no idea where."*

He then relates to you a message left by Carlov that was written in the Gallery, talking about how he has crafted every last figurine and has left to seek new inspiration. Finally, Manny ends by hypothesizing how "you're the new master of the Nintendo Gallery."

Manny also mentions that there is a new figurine in the "vast ocean room," and travelling to the back of that room will reveal the final figurine of Link riding on the King of Red Lions.[image: The final figurine]

Answer (score 0):

You get a statue of the King of Red Lions and Link together. You also receive a letter from the sculpture alongside the satisfaction of completing it.